# sortable change divs depending on index

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to do this, when a user sorts the list, the divs change position depending on the order of the list.

So when the user changes the sortable, the divs in the main sections change. At the moment its not working

here is my code

```
$("#element-list").sortable({
    stop:function(event, ui){
        // new index
        var index = ui.item.index();
        var classs = $(ui.item).attr('class');

        // find the correct div in the main div and update its index
        $('#main').find('.'+classs+'').index(index);

    }
});
```

here is my html

```
<ul id="element-list">
    <li class="blue">Blue Div</li>
    <li class="red">Red Div</li>
    <li class="yellow">Yellow Div</li>
</ul>

<div id="main">

    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

This will loop through the sorted list and then rearrange the corresponding divs in the main div to match.

```
$("#element-list").sortable({
  stop: function (event, ui) {
    $("#element-list li").each(function () {
        var classs = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#main").find('.' + classs).appendTo($("#main"));
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sortable sorts by default, is [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SSqG/) what you are trying to achieve?

```
$("#element-list").sortable();
```

is enough. Make sure that jQueryUI is loaded before calling sortable().

Comment: no, im trying to achieve this. If you sort the blue on so its now in the middle of the list then it change the blue div in the main section